# Play part of an audio file

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have to play an audio part out of a big file (300MB+).

This is my code:

> ```
> // Media source is a local file.
> // datName = "sound.dat"
> // pointer = position in file
> // length  = length of the part to play
>
> try
> {
>     file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync
>           (new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Data/" + datName));
>     // Get the media source as a stream.
>     IRandomAccessStream stream = 
>           await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
>     stream.Seek((ulong)pointer); // This is working, position changes from 0 to pointer
>     stream.Size = (ulong)length; // Is not working, Size remains unchanged at total file size
>     media.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
>     media.Play();
> }
> catch (Exception ex)
> {
>     if (ex is FormatException || ex is ArgumentException)
>     {
>         //ShowFileErrorMsg();
>     }
> }
> ```

Please note the comments on stream Seek and Size. The file is played from position zero.

How can I play the sound from pointer to pointer + length?

Comment: Just an idea - maybe you can set [the position of audio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.position) after it's been loaded, and start it along with Timer (with appropriate interval) which would stop the playback.

Comment: The Audio parts are spoken words of different length. I can not estimate the speaking time to set a timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem by using the binary reader. I read the required area in a byte buffer and convert it to an IRandomAccessStream.

> ```
> StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Data/" + fileName));
> using (Stream stream = (await file.OpenReadAsync()).AsStreamForRead())
> using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
> {
>     reader.BaseStream.Position = pointer;
>     byte[] buffer = reader.ReadBytes((int)length);
>     IRandomAccessStream nstream = new MemoryStream(buffer).AsRandomAccessStream();
>     media.SetSource(nstream, "");
>     media.Play();
> }
> ```

This version is now working.